# Using Tensorflow on smartphones

Tags: java, android, python, mobile, tensorflow

I've been learning a lot about the uses of Machine Learning and Google's Tensorflow. Mostly, developers use Python when developing with Tensorflow. I do realize that other languages can be used with Tensorflow as well, i.e. Java and C++. I see that Google s about to launch Tensorflow Lite that is supposed to be a game changer for mobile devices. My question; can I be safe by learning Tensorflow using Python and still be able to develop mobile apps using this service?

Comment: This question is probably going to be closed because it is largely opinion based. BUT my experience with most libraries/frameworks is: if I learn them in one language that I know, it is easy to adapt them to a different language that I know. Learn the concepts and the syntax will fall easily in place. It would be wise to get a head start on learning the concepts of machine learning now, rather than wait for fear that the syntax will change.

Comment: @BHawk I'm not entirely sure where you see an opinion on here, aside from maybe the idea that people use python with Tensorflow, but that is quite true because python has a ton of supported libraries. And if that's not it, I'm at a loss to your meaning. Also, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677724/tensorflow-why-was-python-the-chosen-language), there's more opinions than stated on my question, but yet a lot of people make really valid points. Besides all of this quarreling, I agree with you on the idea of sticking with one language, then having a smooth transition. Thanks.

Comment: You might find my "Applied TensorFlow in Android Apps" talk useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6Xx67liMCk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes. It would be safe to learn implementing TensorFlow using python and still comfortably develop machine learning enabled mobile apps.

Let me elaborate. Even with TensorFlow Lite, training the data can only happen on the server side; only the prediction, or the inference happens on the mobile device. So typically, you would create your models on TensorFlow, often using python, and then leverage TensorFlow Lite to package that model into your app.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense completely. I would imagine that I could at least run TensorFlow on a server, and I could then stream data from my mobile device to be ran through the model, maybe even be used as future testing data if the predictions appear accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is : yes. You will be safe with python since it’s the main front end language for tensorflow. Also I agree with BHawk’s answer above.

Comment: You will find [this video](https://youtu.be/0r9w3V923rk) during Tensorflow DevSummit useful.

Comment: Good video. Very insightful. Thanks for that.