# Tensorflow inference performance with python vs. c++ . vs java

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to run inference using tensorflow. Trying to decide among the API's to use: python, c++, or java. What's the factors that impact performance? Are there any benchmarks? Any knowledge or tips appreciated!

Comment: There should be no difference in performance as the API is just used to express the model and create data flow graph. Look at this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35678837/98810